# After resizing PV/PVC in AKS using standard LRS storage class, Artifactory > monitoring > storage section still shows old storage space. How to fix?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, artifactory, azure-aks

Issue:

Need to increase the filestore size after resizing my PV but the filestore size is not changing, even if I set the PV/PVC to 800gi or 300gi, it's still stuck at 205

```js
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: artifactory-pv-claim
  namespace: test
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 250Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  storageClassName: "custom-artifactory"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resize the PVC, you can edit the PVC to change the storage request to ask for more space. But to make the update works, [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/) shows the way:

> File system expansion must be triggered by terminating the pod using
> the volume. More specifically:
>
> Edit the PVC to request more space. Once underlying volume has been
> expanded by the storage provider, then the PersistentVolume object
> will reflect the updated size and the PVC will have the
> FileSystemResizePending condition.

And here is the screenshot of my test:

before change:

[image]

after change, but before recreate pod:

[image]

after recreate pod:

[image]

Comment: do I delete pvc then reapply? or do i edit to request more? If I delete and change the yaml and apply again, it keeps creating a new pv, it doesn't attach to the existing pv, is this the expected I uninstall the pod then reinstall?

Comment: adding comment here so people can see what worked. @Charles Xu you are right. For anyone else who comes here. change the replicaset of the pod to 0, so it terminates, then edit pvc to update the storage request, then change replicaset back to what it was and you will see new size. Fixed my issues. Thanks you!